# Envíar a usuario a una Web despues de escanear código QR (Uso Simple Qr-code)

Tags: laravel

Tengo Simple Qr-code y me funciona bien, solo que al escanear el código me muestra como mensaje la URL que tengo en el código, lo que necesito es que al escanearlo me envíe a una URL.

Muestro el código con blade así:

```
{!! QrCode::size(200)->generate('http://www.simplesoftware.io') !!}
```

Y en mi controlador:

```
Route::get('show/qr', 'ShowController@qr')->name('show.qr');
```

Comment: No sé si entiendo. Ahí estás generando un qr, pero si un usuario lo escanea, va a ser el usuario quien decida si accede a la url o no. Imagínate que en tu qr pongas `http://www.terobotodo.hoy`, no podés obligar a alguien a entrar

Comment: Ahora, si tu aplicación Laravel está decodificando un qr que está en otro sitio, ahí sí puedes manejar tú que quieres que suceda

Comment: Hola, disculpa lo tarde. Entiendo, muchas gracias.